# Got only first row in table when using Selenium scraping (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath

I'm trying to scrape the whole table from: https://free-proxy-list.net/

And I managed to scrape it but it resulted in only the first row of the table instead of 20 rows.

I saw previous similar questions that were answered and I have tried the solutions given but my selenium was unable to locate the element when I use `.//` for my xpath.

```python
for bod in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='proxylisttable']/tbody"):
    col = bod.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='proxylisttable']/tbody/tr")
    for c in col:
        ip = c.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="proxylisttable"]/tbody/tr/td[1]')
        port = c.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="proxylisttable"]/tbody/tr/td[2]')
        code = c.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="proxylisttable"]/tbody/tr/td[3]')
        country = c.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="proxylisttable"]/tbody/tr/td[4][@class = "hm"]')
        anonymity = c.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="proxylisttable"]/tbody/tr/td[5]')
        google = c.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="proxylisttable"]/tbody/tr/td[6][@class = "hm"]')
```

My code resulted in only scraping the first row 20 times instead of getting 20 rows. The rows are indicated at `ip`, `port`, `code`, etc. I have tried multiple types of xpath syntax but still end up the same.

Comment: You want get value each cell ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To handle dynamic element induce `WebdriverWait` and `visibility_of_all_elements_located`
to wait for the element and then use following xpath.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver=webdriver.Chrome("path of the chrome driver")
driver.get('https://free-proxy-list.net/')

rows= WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//table[@id='proxylisttable']/tbody//tr")))
for row in rows:
    ip=row.find_element_by_xpath('./td[1]').text
    port=row.find_element_by_xpath('./td[2]').text
    code=row.find_element_by_xpath('./td[3]').text
    country=row.find_element_by_xpath('./td[4]').get_attribute('textContent')
    Anonymity=row.find_element_by_xpath('./td[5]').text
    google=row.find_element_by_xpath('./td[6]').get_attribute('textContent')
    https=row.find_element_by_xpath('./td[7]').text
    lastchecked=row.find_element_by_xpath('./td[8]').get_attribute('textContent')
    print("IP :{}, Port:{}, code:{}, country:{}, Anonymity:{}, google:{}, https:{}, last_checked:{}".format(ip,port,code,country,Anonymity,google,https,lastchecked))
```

**Output on console:**

```
IP :185.132.133.173, Port:8080, code:NL, country:Netherlands, Anonymity:elite proxy, google:no, https:yes, last_checked:1 minute ago
IP :181.112.225.78, Port:58948, code:EC, country:Ecuador, Anonymity:elite proxy, google:no, https:yes, last_checked:1 minute ago
IP :134.249.149.219, Port:35795, code:UA, country:Ukraine, Anonymity:elite proxy, google:no, https:yes, last_checked:1 minute ago
IP :195.20.30.54, Port:55182, code:UA, country:Ukraine, Anonymity:elite proxy, google:no, https:yes, last_checked:1 minute ago
IP :14.102.69.170, Port:53347, code:IN, country:India, Anonymity:elite proxy, google:no, https:yes, last_checked:1 minute ago
IP :182.53.193.108, Port:54543, code:TH, country:Thailand, Anonymity:elite proxy, google:no, https:yes, last_checked:1 minute ago
IP :159.224.221.175, Port:58299, code:UA, country:Ukraine, Anonymity:elite proxy, google:no, https:yes, last_checked:1 minute ago
IP :36.89.188.123, Port:49725, code:ID, country:Indonesia, Anonymity:elite proxy, google:no, https:yes, last_checked:1 minute ago
IP :103.231.163.58, Port:43620, code:BD, country:Bangladesh, Anonymity:elite proxy, google:no, https:yes, last_checked:1 minute ago
IP :114.130.92.14, Port:49167, code:BD, country:Bangladesh, Anonymity:elite proxy, google:no, https:yes, last_checked:1 minute ago
IP :177.54.200.10, Port:49501, code:BR, country:Brazil, Anonymity:elite proxy, google:no, https:yes, last_checked:1 minute ago
IP :77.38.21.239, Port:8080, code:SI, country:Slovenia, Anonymity:elite proxy, google:no, https:yes, last_checked:1 minute ago
IP :78.137.89.161, Port:8080, code:YE, country:Yemen, Anonymity:transparent, google:no, https:no, last_checked:1 minute ago
IP :103.216.147.49, Port:8080, code:IN, country:India, Anonymity:transparent, google:no, https:no, last_checked:1 minute ago
IP :195.250.188.210, Port:8080, code:EE, country:Estonia, Anonymity:transparent, google:no, https:no, last_checked:1 minute ago
IP :5.196.255.171, Port:3128, code:FR, country:France, Anonymity:transparent, google:no, https:no, last_checked:1 minute ago
IP :109.234.112.250, Port:46675, code:GE, country:Georgia, Anonymity:transparent, google:no, https:no, last_checked:1 minute ago
IP :186.225.48.178, Port:8080, code:BR, country:Brazil, Anonymity:transparent, google:no, https:no, last_checked:1 minute ago
IP :101.255.64.142, Port:35401, code:ID, country:Indonesia, Anonymity:elite proxy, google:no, https:yes, last_checked:1 minute ago
IP :160.119.129.42, Port:57557, code:GN, country:Guinea, Anonymity:elite proxy, google:no, https:yes, last_checked:1 minute ago
```

Comment: I finally did it! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is in this line :

```
col = bod.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='proxylisttable']/tbody/tr")
```

The correct syntax is :

```
col = bod.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='proxylisttable']/tbody/tr[insert count here]")
```

Like this :

```
table = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='proxylisttable']/tbody")
rows = table.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='proxylisttable']/tbody/tr")

for i in range (1, len(rows)+1):
    row = table.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='proxylisttable']/tbody/tr[" +str(i) +']')
    for c in row:
        ip = c.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="proxylisttable"]/tbody/tr/td[1]')
        port = c.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="proxylisttable"]/tbody/tr/td[2]')
        code = c.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="proxylisttable"]/tbody/tr/td[3]')
        country = c.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="proxylisttable"]/tbody/tr/td[4][@class = "hm"]')
        anonymity = c.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="proxylisttable"]/tbody/tr/td[5]')
        google = c.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="proxylisttable"]/tbody/tr/td[6][@class = "hm"]')
```

Comment: I tried this method and unfortunately now it only returns the first row as well. It did not increase the 'i' at the end.

Comment: sure the `i` not increase ?

Comment: yea :( unfortunately it did not. I was trying to insert the `i` somewhere else in the code as well. but same results. Also I think it has something to do with the `tr[' + i + ']'`. I think the `i` there needs to be `str(i)`

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code to have one index inside your second for loop which will loop from 1 to length of cols and use it to find each column element

```
ip = c.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="proxylisttable"]/tbody/tr[index]/td[1]')
```

P.S.: Please modify the syntax as per python.